# Keeping the contents of an array after its function call ends. (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Lets say I have the following code.

```
double *return_array(void) {
   double foo[2];
   foo[0] = 5;
   foo[1] = 6;
   cout << foo << endl;
   cout << foo[0] << endl << foo[1] << endl;
   return foo;
}

double *bar = return_array()
cout << bar << endl;
cout << bar[0] << endl << bar[1] << endl;
```

Now, bar and foo are still the same pointer but what was there has changed completely. How can I get around this? Basically, I need to pass 6 or 9 doubles from a function. What should I do?

Comment: In addition to the good replies below, if you have a fixed number of values you may want to create a struct|class with them and return that instead. Depending on the usage of your values it may be easier to read/handle e.g. using g=foo[gravity] instead: g=foo.gravity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you would pass in your pre-allocated memory into the function:

```
int barsize = 2;
double *bar = new double[barsize];
fill_array( bar, barsize );
cout << bar << endl;
cout << bar[0] << endl << bar[1] << endl;
delete [] bar;

void fill_array( double *foo, int foosize )
{
  if ( foosize < 2 )
    return;

  foo[0] = 5;
  foo[1] = 6;
  cout << foo << endl;
  cout << foo[0] << endl << foo[1] << endl;
}
```

The rule I use is... always allocate and delete memory in the same spot.

Or use a std::vector.  They're nice =)  I never use arrays anymore.

Comment: However, that only works if you know how much you're going to need to allocate before the function is called. If the size of the results can vary, passing in a pre-allocated space won't work.

Comment: @Dav: And that is why a lot of C functions have a pre-flight mode. Pass a NULL pointer and it returns the size you need. Allocate the memory and call again. Which is why we love C++ std::vector. The rule about allocating and deleting in the same spot is good one.

Comment: Ya... switch to using vectors if you can.

Comment: Yup. This was what I was looking for. Just took the double* bar declaration out of the function. Easy and understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use a vector.

```
std::vector<double> return_array(void) {
   std::vector<double> foo;
   foo.push_back(5);
   foo.push_back(6);
   cout << foo[0] << endl << foo[1] << endl;
   return foo;
}
```

---

This is a better way, So you avoid copying the vector :

```
void fillVector(std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(6);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec;

    fillVector(vec);
}
```

---

> Now, bar and foo are still the same
>   pointer but what was there has changed
>   completely.

Because `foo` is allocated on the stack of the function, it gets deallocatd when the function returns. So, `bar` is actually pointing no where!

Answer (score 1):

Allocate the memory on the heap instead of the stack using the `new` keyword:

```
double *return_array(void) {
    double * foo = new double [2];
    foo[0] = 5;
    foo[1] = 6;
    return foo;
}
```

Then the code that calls the function will eventually have to free up the memory when it's done with it using `delete`:

```
double * foo = return_array();
// ...
delete [] foo;
```

Comment: You should always delete in the same place you create memory. This will cause memory leaks down the road due to mis-use.

Comment: Agreed, although you could still follow that rule with the above function by creating a complementary function to free the memory. But I would usually just do it the way you did in your answer.

Comment: ... or you could return an auto_ptr and not worry about it =)

Comment: Is your answer equivalent to @Kieveli's answer? What exactly does new do?

Comment: It would work the same. I think we posted at the same time, or I posted after Jeremy.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new` to allocate memory that isn't scoped to the function.

Don't forget to `delete[]` the memory when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the result on the heap or, better yet, use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always returning a fixed number of elements and are willing to use TR1 extensions (or Boost), I'd go with `std::tr1::tuple` rather than `vector` or an array. It's a template class, so you'll want to typedef it, along the lines of:

```
typedef std::tr1::tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double> six_tuple;
```

Use `make_tuple()` with the appropriate number (and type) of arguments to create the tuple your function returns, and access its contents with the templated `get<N>()` function, e.g.:

```
six_tuple foo = std::tr1::make_tuple(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
std::cout << std::tr1::get<0>(foo) << std::endl; // prints '1.0'
```

The compiler will introspect on the number and types of arguments to `make_tuple()`, and throw an error if you're trying to assign to the wrong sort of tuple.

I prefer this to having to manage the memory myself, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Clear as mud. The next developer to try to figure out what you were trying to do would add your name to a list of curse words.

Comment: What's unclear? I freely admit the template parameters look freakish, but that's what a typedef is for. tuple is part of the standard as of TR1, and supports all kinds of C++ features that arrays don't. You can use them with comparison operators (equality, less-than, &c), as arguments to stream operators, and so on. Plus, if something in return_array() throws an exception, the tuple (if it had been created) self-destructs when the stack unwinds. You don't get that with allocation via new.

If std::tr1::tuple scares you, all I can say is, std::tr1::bind will make you run screaming.

Comment: I can picture my question being asked by anyone learning the basics of C++. Your answer my be well accepted by a more seasoned programmer, but is overkill for this situation. Thanks for the detail, though.

Comment: It wouldn't scare me personally - I have 11+ years of C++ experience.  It would scare the other developers who have less experience.  I would still have to look up the tuple because of its infrequent use, which would take more of my time.  Then I would wonder why you didn't use the vector.  Then I would look for your comment explaining why you wrote something in a way that 80-90% of other developers wouldn't have even considered.  Dismissing your unorthodox coding as being my 'fear of code' is a dubious logical argument, and sadly not the first time I've heard it.